# Network packets don't reach local host when connected with to Openstack VPS with Openvpn server

Tags: iptables, openvpn, linux-networking, nat, tcpdump

So here is an issue.

I've installed OpenVPN server on Openstack VPS (hostigger, if this is important). I've used guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

All good up to the point, when I could establish vpn connection. But when I try to reach almost any site - I got connection timeout.

I've disabled ufw for sake of debugging.

Iptables:

`$ iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L`

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 43527 packets, 3644888 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 4095 packets, 441234 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 33 packets, 2279 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 33 packets, 2279 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1453   104793 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ens3    10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0
```

`ens3` is my default interface on server.

When I try to `tracert` from local machine

```
$ tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [172.217.16.46]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    73 ms    73 ms    72 ms  10.8.0.1
  2    76 ms    86 ms    75 ms  185.181.208.1
  3    74 ms    81 ms    73 ms  static-217-195-202-1.fibersunucu.com.tr [217.195.202.1]
  4    79 ms    75 ms    74 ms  static-177-159-92-77.sadecehosting.net [77.92.159.177]
  5    75 ms    75 ms    75 ms  212.156.128.169.static.turktelekom.com.tr [212.156.128.169]
  6    74 ms    75 ms    77 ms  00-atakoy-xrs-t2-1---00-atakoy-t3-7.statik.turktelekom.com.tr [212.156.120.130]
  7   106 ms    75 ms    74 ms  00-gayrettepe-xrs-t2-1---00-atakoy-xrs-t2-1.statik.turktelekom.com.tr [81.212.203.102]
  8     *        *       75 ms  00-ebgp-gayrettepe-k---00-gayrettepe-xrs-t2-1.statik.turktelekom.com.tr [81.212.201.195]
  9    81 ms    76 ms    75 ms  212.156.120.178.26-eskisehir-t3-1.06-ulus-t3-7.statik.turktelekom.com.tr [212.156.120.178]
 10    83 ms    86 ms    83 ms  307-sof-col-1---00-ebgp-gayrettepe-k.statik.turktelekom.com.tr [212.156.104.22]
 11   112 ms   103 ms   124 ms  74.125.51.94
 12   106 ms   106 ms   111 ms  108.170.250.168
 13   145 ms   147 ms   142 ms  108.170.226.42
 14   132 ms   132 ms   134 ms  72.14.239.245
 15   132 ms   132 ms   132 ms  216.239.58.5
 16   136 ms   132 ms   141 ms  108.170.250.193
 17   132 ms   132 ms   132 ms  74.125.251.103
 18   135 ms   131 ms   132 ms  waw02s14-in-f14.1e100.net [172.217.16.46]

Trace complete.
```

Ping also works.

I've run `tcpdump`

`tcpdump -A -s 0 'src president.gov.by and tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'`

For a request from local machine like this `curl -sSL -D - http://president.gov.by/robots.txt` - it works - I see robots.txt

tcpdump output:

```
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
23:30:02.115218 IP 178.124.139.203.http > 10.8.0.6.51344: Flags [P.], seq 272799366:272799764, ack 63565427, win 96, length 398: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
E.....@./.(..|..
....P...B.....sP..`....HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 20:30:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 173
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 04:28:06 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes

User-agent: *
Disallow: /ru/search_ru
Disallow: /en/search_en
Disallow: /by/search_by
Disallow: /*printv
Host: president.gov.by
Sitemap: http://president.gov.by/sitemap.xml
```

But when I try `curl -sSL -D - http://president.gov.by/`

I see this in server's tcpdump output, but never on my local machine:

```
23:30:39.493302 IP 178.124.139.203.http > 10.8.0.6.51366: Flags [.], seq 2193652739:2193654079, ack 1503148830, win 96, length 1340: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
E..d..@......|..
....P....|.Y.;.P..`)"..HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 20:30:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 112378
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 16:38:45 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head>
blah-blah-blah some html here

23:30:39.493315 IP 178.124.139.203.http > 10.8.0.6.51366: Flags [.], seq 1340:2680, ack 1, win 96, length 1340: HTTP
E..d..@......|..
....P.....?Y.;.P..`........................ .................... ................, .. .......... ...................... .................., .........., .............."/>
</head>
<body>
  blah-blah-blah some html here

23:30:39.493317 IP 178.124.139.203.http > 10.8.0.6.51366: Flags [.], seq 2680:4020, ack 1, win 96, length 1340: HTTP
E..d..@......|..
....P.....{Y.;.P..`I".. class="search" id="search_form">
        <div class="search_left"></div>
        blah-blah-blah some html here

23:30:39.493320 IP 178.124.139.203.http > 10.8.0.6.51366: Flags [.], seq 4020:5360, ack 1, win 96, length 1340: HTTP
E..d..@......|..
....P......Y.;.P..`...............">..............</a>blah-blah-blah some html here                                </div>
                <div class="top_m

23:30:39.493323 IP 178.124.139.203.http > 10.8.0.6.51366: Flags [.], seq 5360:6700, ack 1, win 96, length 1340: HTTP
E..d..@......|..
....P......Y.;.P..`/...enu_right"></div>
                blah-blah-blah some html here

23:30:39.493325 IP 178.124.139.203.http > 10.8.0.6.51366: Flags [.], seq 6700:8040, ack 1, win 96, length 1340: HTTP
E..d..@......|..
....P...../Y.;.P..`u>.blah-blah-blah some html here
                                                                                                <div class="bm_da
23:30:39.494547 IP 178.124.139.203.http > 10.8.0.6.51366: Flags [P.], seq 8040:8173, ack 1, win 96, length 133: HTTP
E.....@...gp.|..
....P.....kY.;.P..`....te">25 ........ 2019 ........</div>
                                                <a href="http://president.gov.by/ru/news_ru/view/rabochaja-poezdka-v-vetkovskij-rajon-gomel
23:30:39.633147 IP 178.124.139.203.http > 10.8.0.6.51366: Flags [.], seq 12193:13533, ack 1, win 96, length 1340: HTTP
E..d..@...b..|..
....P......Y.;.P..`blah-blah-blah some html here

23:30:40.186755 IP 178.124.139.203.http > 10.8.0.6.51366: Flags [.], seq 0:1340, ack 1, win 96, length 1340: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
E..d..@...b..|..
....P....|.Y.;.P..`)"..HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 20:30:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 112378
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 16:38:45 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head>
       blah-blah-blah some html here

23:30:41.575025 IP 178.124.139.203.http > 10.8.0.6.51366: Flags [.], seq 0:1340, ack 1, win 96, length 1340: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
E..d..@...b..|..
....P....|.Y.;.P..`)"..HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 20:30:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 112378
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 16:38:45 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head>
       blah-blah-blah some html here

23:30:44.350585 IP 178.124.139.203.http > 10.8.0.6.51366: Flags [.], seq 0:1340, ack 1, win 96, length 1340: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
E..d..@...b..|..
....P....|.Y.;.P..`)"..HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 20:30:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 112378
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 16:38:45 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head>
       blah-blah-blah some html here
^C
11 packets captured
15 packets received by filter
3 packets dropped by kernel
```

I'm stuck here. Why could I reach robots.txt, but not bigger files (index.html, etc)